# sql injection with union

Tags: mysql, sql

So I am doing a little sql injection challenge because I wanted to learn about it and I have a question. I type `'hi'` into the HTML form and I get this back as a response

```
Error: The following error occurred: [near "hi": syntax error]

Query: SELECT * FROM personnel WHERE name=''hi''
```

The information we need to get is located in a table called users. I was looking at sql and I see here the union operator which combines the results of 2+ select statements.

So, I try this as input: `1 UNION SELECT * FROM users` and I get nothing back so it looks like it searched from that input as a name in table personnel. I thought this would work because the query would look like: `SELECT * FROM personnel WHERE name=1 UNION SELECT * FROM users`. Am I not understanding how the union operator works or is something else wrong in my input

Answer (score 0):

This one:

```
set @hi = "'hi'";
select @hi;

SELECT * FROM personnel  WHERE name="'hi'"
```

Simulate:

```
insert into personnel (`name`) values("'hi'");
insert into personnel (`name`) values("'hello'");
select * from personnel where `name` != "'hi'"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 -- you can't use a double '' in sql query
 Query: SELECT * FROM personnel WHERE name='hi'
```

Comment: Im aware I used the double quotes to see what their SQL statement was and to check if they filtered anything for injection.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the SQL is invalid because `personnel` and `users` have different shape.  You need to inject something that is identical to the initial `select`.

Also your entire problem goes away if you have parameterised queries instead of concatenating into SQL.